# Ошибка 500 при получении запроса

Tags: php, wordpress, vkontakte-api

В чем может быть ошибка? При сохранении/добавлении записи отправляет кросспост в вк с получением шортлинка вк:

```
if ( get_option( 'vkapi_crosspost_link' ) ) {
    $key = '1e140f104078def9d259e15016a96fa0b1cca6a5d4f9225355029a5c12121619a35c4fcf90d39aa79724c';
    $request_params = array(
        'access_token' => $key,
        'url' => get_permalink( $post_id ),
        'v' => '5.63'
    );
    $get_params = http_build_query($request_params);
    $result = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/utils.getShortLink?'. $get_params));

    $attachments[] = $result -> response[0] -> short_url;
}
```

Comment: Не здесь 500. Вставил код на сайт - работает. Ну возвращает Validation Required. Но не 500 же.

Comment: Это отдельный плагин VKontakte API. Только сам плагин не может сокращать ссылки

Comment: 500 - это ошибка парсинга вашего скрипта. Синтаксис неверный. Ищите в тех строках, где правили плагин.